# Закрытие QComboBox для редактирования

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Есть QComboBox, который по дефолту должент быть в состоянии editable, но по нажатию кнопки он должен быть закрыт для редактирования, при этом сохранив текст, который в него внесли до этого. Нашла для QLineEdit функцию setReadOnly(bool), которой просто передаю флаг, который стал тру при нажатии кнопки. Возможно не всю документацию еще перелопатила, но ничего не нашла похожего.Заранее спасибо за помощь:)

Answer (score 2):

Но ведь для этого ответа нужно всего лишь открыть документацию по [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QComboBox.html), нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, ввести там «editable» и найти [`setEditable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#editable-prop). Это же гораздо проще, чем набрать вопрос на SO!

---

Также можно воспользоваться функцией [`lineEdit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#lineEdit), чтобы выставить `QLineEdit` в read only: `lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);`

Comment: При setEditable(false) не остается текст, а появляется просто пустой комбобокс. Мне нужно что б там был текст, который нельзя редачить.

Comment: @МашаГрачова, обновил